# Jdbc - Connect remote Mysql Database error

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

[SOLVED]

I finally got solve the problem, is everything alright with the connection...

The problem was in a SQL Query, i was doing a select in table with name "arduinoData" and the really name is "arduinodata".

That way works locally, but when i tried online, it doesn't.

Because this, the return was 'null', and Java was trying to parsetoInt that and was showing error.

I'm so sorry for trouble, thank you to all.

---

I'm using JDBC to connect my program to a MySQL database.

I already put the port number and yes, my database have permission to access.

When i use localhost work perfectly, but when i try connect to a remote MySQL database, show this error on console.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at serial.BDArduino.<clinit>(BDArduino.java:25)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 1 segundo)
```

Thank you in Advance !

Comment: you also have to enable remote access in mysql, by default it only accepts access from localhost, did you enable it?

Answer (score 2):

*Note:* This was originally a comment but got too long. It seems people see NFE and guess it's port that's null. Which is misleading. Here is a WORKING code showing port is not necessary. Please avoid misleading answers.

```
        try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          String sourceURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/sodb";

          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sourceURL, "naishe", "p2ssword");
          Statement st = conn.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select count(*) from test_tab");
          while(rs.next()){
              System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
          }
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
          System.err.println(cnfe);
        } catch(SQLException sqle) {
          System.err.println(sqle);
        }
```

It prints `3` (which is number of records in the table test_tab) correctly.

---

If you are using *standard driver*, you **do not need port**, it defaults to 3306! See here 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

> JDBC URL Format
>
> The JDBC URL format for MySQL Connector/J is as follows, with items in square brackets ([, ]) being optional:
>
> `jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database] »
>       [?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...`
>
> If the host name is not specified, it defaults to 127.0.0.1. **If the port is not specified, it defaults to 3306, the default port number for MySQL servers.**

Comment: @NandkumarTekale Did you actually read the code. I am using MySQL and NOT using port and it work! you do NOT have to provide port. It defaults to 3306.

Comment: I will remove downvote, if you show me proof on documentation

Comment: @NandkumarTekale It's not for your downvote that I worry, it's amount of RTFD people need.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have missed port number in your connection string.

```
static String url = "jdbc:mysql://mysql.mydomain.com.br:3306/myDB";
```

Instead of

```
static String url = "jdbc:mysql://mysql.mydomain.com.br/myDB";
```

Now if getting same error mean you might replace **mysql.mydomain.com.br** with IP address as follows:

Just supply the IP / hostname of the remote machine in your database connection string, instead of mysql.mydomain.com.br. For example:

```
jdbc:mysql://172.16.15.225:3306/yourdatabase
```

Also check there is no firewall blocking the access to port 3306.

Make sure the user you are connecting with is allowed to connect from this particular hostname. For development environments it is safe to do this by

```
'username'@'%'
```

This is for grant permission for users
[GRANT manual.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

Comment: Did you use Ip address and port number? Now what's error getting?

Comment: @GuilhermeRuiz Please update your stack trace in your question it would be help ful to all

Comment: The same error -- java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at serial.BDArduino.<clinit>(BDArduino.java:25)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 1 segundo)

Comment: int sql8 = Integer.parseInt(Sql.getDBinfo("SELECT * FROM arduinoData WHERE id=1", "pin8"));
check in this line.In your application your trying to convert string into Numberic.But it seems not working fine.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `port numbers` in your `connection url as 3306`,  and also please make sure about the user permission to the databse access if not granted ,you are supposed to grant the permission to the  user to access the remote database ,please refer the [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/allow-mysql-client-connection/)

Comment: I have sure that im using port number and my database have permission

Comment: what is your table design for `arduinoData`? from my understanding indicates that the application has tried to convert a string to one of the numeric types i think so

Comment: Please let me know reason for down vote , it may help me to correct my mistake? Thanks for downvote

Comment: not a downvoter, exception is `NumberFormatException` which got after reading values from database, so your answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale Okies.Never mind.I suggested as per the question tag as he mentioned . Later for stack trace NFE error i have commented about the string conversion to numeric type.